# How to partition a pen drive with Disk Utility in El Capitan?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

I've a 16 GB pen drive and I want to partition it like this:

two MBR partitions:

1. FAT - 1GB
2. default (HFS Plus journaled) - remaining.

How to do this in El Capitan?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Disk Utility and select the disk in the sidebar (not a partition).
2. Click Partition in the toolbar.
3. Enter the first partition information.
4. Click the **+** button to add a second partition.
5. Enter the second partition information. The size will be entered automatically from the remaining space.
6. Click Apply.

Comment: I want the partition scheme to be MBR and this disk utility is not allowing me to have 2 different positions when I select MBR and format it. What should I do?

Comment: @Akash If it's not already MBR, use Erase to set MBR, then follow the instructions above.

Comment: I've tried that, when I set MBR and erase the disk it doesn't allow me to have two different partitions, it shows only one volume. I'm stuck.